# Using Max with CTE and CASE T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, max, common-table-expression

I am trying to use `MAX()` to select the most recent placement date within our database, and use `Table_CTE` so I can then select and filter between the dates desired.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Rangetill DATE, @Rangefrom DATE

    SET @rangefrom = DATEADD(day, -50, GETDATE()) 
    SET @Rangetill = DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE());

    WITH Table_CTE (Name, ID, Rangefrom, Rangetill, StatusID, Statusdate) AS 
    (
        SELECT
            PE.Personname + ' ' + PE.Surname [Name],
            A.ApplicantId,
            @rangefrom [Expiry warning from],
            @rangetill [Expiry warning till],
            A.Statusid,
            selected = CASE 
                          WHEN P.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND P.EndDate > A.StatusDate
                             THEN CONVERT(DATE, P.EndDate, 103) 
                             ELSE CONVERT(DATE, A.StatusDate, 103)
                       END
        FROM
            Applicants AS A 
        LEFT JOIN 
            Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
        LEFT JOIN 
            Placements AS P on A.applicantid = P.Applicantid
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table_CTE
    WHERE table_cte.Statusdate BETWEEN @Rangetill AND @Rangefrom
      AND (Table_CTE.StatusID = 58 OR Table_CTE.statusid = 63)
    ORDER BY Name DESC
END
```

The above selects the right information but also selects duplicate applicants with placement end dates (p.enddate) as they could have been placed more than once. The WHERE clause  also limits the most recent enddate to within the range provided by the Variables and as there needs to be a log there will be multiple end dates. so my solution or idea would be to uses a max() within the Case or CTE Select. However I am not sure how to use or work with Max() in this case.

In this case I would like to check and return the `Max(p.enddate)` if it exists and store that in the statusdate of Table_CTE.

Is this possible and is it the best way to provide this information in a stored procedure?

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-max-with-group-by.php

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using multiple calls to `GetDate()`, whether in a single statement or multiple statements, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Comment: @HABO that is definitely worth noting,  I will be sure to remember it and make the necessary changes here.

Comment: Why can't you use MAX()?

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci I was not sure how to use MAX() in this example. I am also learning programming at the same time. (With SQL -server becoming a new part of my role).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Declare 

@Rangetill date,
@Rangefrom date

SET @rangefrom = DATEADD(day, -50, GETDATE()) 
SET @Rangetill = DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE());


With Table_CTE ( ID, Rangefrom, Rangetill, Statusdate)
AS (
Select 
  A.ApplicantId
, @rangefrom [Expiry warning from]
, @rangetill [Expiry warning till]
, selected = CASE 
        WHEN max(P.EndDate) IS NOT NULL AND max(P.EndDate) > max(A.StatusDate)
        THEN  max(CONVERT(DATE, P.EndDate, 103))

        ELSE max(CONVERT(DATE, A.StatusDate, 103))
END


FROM       Applicants AS A 
LEFT JOIN Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Placements AS P on A.applicantid = P.Applicantid

GROUP BY A.ApplicantId

)

SELECT 
  PE.PersonName + ' ' + PE.Surname [NAME]
, A.ApplicantId 
, Table_CTE.ID
, Table_CTE.Statusdate
, @Rangefrom [Range from]
, @Rangetill [Range till]


FROM Table_CTE
LEFT JOIN Applicants AS A ON A.ApplicantId = Table_CTE.ID
LEFT JOIN Person as PE on PE.PersonID = A.ApplicantId
WHERE  table_cte.Statusdate Between @Rangetill and @Rangefrom
AND (A.StatusID = 58 or A.statusid = 63 )


Order by PE.PersonName + ' '+ PE.Surname desc
END
```

Really messy way around things but I got my solution by removing all but the variables and ID from CTE so I could select Max(DATE) on both A.statusdate and P.EndDate.

By doing this I could group by A.ApplicantID and rejoin specific tables outside of the CTE in order to get Applicant Name and Status ID back into my results set.

Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: Careful, you are filtering the max statusdate (different from geting the max status date from the filter). Make sure that this is the correct approach for your data.

Answer (score 0):

In the CTE would be more efficient but this is easier

```
SELECT c.[Name], max(c.Statusdate)
FROM Table_CTE c
WHERE c.Statusdate Between @Rangetill and @Rangefrom
  AND c.StatusID in (58, 63)
group by c.[Name]
```

Add the other columns on your own

Comment: Hi @Paparazzo This removes the Duplicates and does indeed select the most recent record. So thank you ! however I do need it to select the Max Within the case as my WHERE clause includes people who shouldn't be within the '@rangetill' and '@rangefrom' (The have been placed recently)

Comment: What makes you think it does not do that?

Comment: By looking at what is returned in the query, I have 4 applicant records that are all in current placements with end dates that are for at least 3 weeks away and although they have an end date within the 50 - 90 day scope the true end date is not.

Comment: Can't help you.  I can guarantee that where clause is applied.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look either way